# Facing issue with stripe failed payment webhook

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, strip

I managing the failed payment webhook in my website but I am facing issue that `invoice.payment_failed` gets received before `invoice.created` which creating issue. Because on failed payment the system is updating the status of invoice but the invoice havnt been created becasue the   `invoice.created` havent been called. I dont know what am I missing. I am using laravel ans spark for stripe management

Comment: Yes "Stripe does not guarantee delivery of events in the order in which they are generated." What do you mean exactly with "the system is updating the status of invoice"? Do you mean you update some saved document (invoice) in your DB and you save the document only when you get the `created` webhook?

Comment: I mean when the invoice.created event fired the system records the invoice in db and has the status as open and when it fails the status becomes fail, so when fail event gets called first it creates error that invoice not found

Answer (score 0):

Given the order of delivery for webhook events is not guaranteed, you have a couple options.

1. Create the record of the invoice in your system a soon as you receive a webhook notification for any new invoice ID.
2. When you receive a webhook notification, add it to a queue for processing, and process the queue in priority order where invoice.created events are processed first. You'll likely want to build in some sort of delay.